# Как при выборе checkbox активировать блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при выборе checkbox с `id="ru"`активировать блок `.block-ru`, а при выборе checkbox с `id="ua"`активировать блок `.block-ua`? При этом, при выборе одного checkbox, другой должен дезактивироваться,  а при повторном нажатии на уже активированный checkbox, этот активированный checkbox также должен дезактивироваться. Можно ли такое реализовать? Спасибо!

```css
.block-ru,
.block-ua {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-box">
<label class="label_ru"><input type="checkbox" name="ru" id="ru" value="1">Россия</label>
<label class="label_ua"><input type="checkbox" name="ua" id="ua" value="1">Украина</label>
</div>
<div class="block-ru">Выбрана Россия</div>
<div class="block-ua">Выбрана Украина</div>
```

Comment: У input есть событие onchange просто сделайте метод на JavaScript, который будет обрабатывать все в ответ на это событие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  $(".blocks").hide();
  $("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function(){
    this.checked = false;  
  });
  if (this.checked)
    $("." + $(this).data("blockclass")).show();
});
```

```css
.block-ru,
.block-ua {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-box">
<label class="label_ru"><input type="checkbox" name="ru" id="ru" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ru">Россия</label>
<label class="label_ua"><input type="checkbox" name="ua" id="ua" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ua">Украина</label>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-ru">Выбрана Россия</div>
<div class="blocks block-ua">Выбрана Украина</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Обработчик изменения чекбокса пропиши. Данный пример подразумевает, что подключена библиотека jQuery, а также блоков выбора стран может быть больше, чем 2:

```
$('#block-box input').on('change',function(){
  var th = $(this),
      $blocks = $('[class^="block-"]');
  // Если выбрали текущий блок
  if(th.prop('checked')){
    // Убрать отметки с других чекбоксов, кроме текущего
    th.closest('#block-box').find('input').not(th).prop('checked', false);
    // Скрыть все блоки стран, из них выбрать нужный блок и отобразить его
    $blocks.hide().filter('.block-'+th.attr('name')).show();
  } 
  // Если сняли отметку
  else {
    $blocks.hide();
  }
});
```